# feature style base on the map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

**Solution: Create two different layers with the same source or use the solution of Mike.**

is there a way to set the style of a feature based on the map where it is shown? I can´t find a way to get the map attributes in the style function:

```
var styleBuilding = function(feature){
  console.log(feature);
  return [
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'orange'
      })
    }),
    geometry: function(feature) {
      var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
      return new ol.geom.Point(coordinates[2]);
    }
  })
];
};
```

best regards
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View resolution is available as the second parameter to a style function.  Any other view property (e.g. the center) can be obtained by referencing the view in the style function, so in this examples point color is set depending on which quadrant of the view the point is displayed in

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
              features: [
                new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([1e6, 1e6])),
                new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([1e6, -1e6])),
                new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([-1e6, -1e6])),
                new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([-1e6, 1e6])),
              ]
            }),
            style: function(feature){
              let color;
              const coordinate = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
              const viewCenter = map.getView().getCenter();
              if (coordinate[0] < viewCenter[0]){
                if (coordinate[1] < viewCenter[1]){
                  color = 'red';
                } else {
                  color = 'orange';
                }
              } else {
                if (coordinate[1] < viewCenter[1]){
                  color = 'green';
                } else {
                  color = 'blue';
                }
              }
              return [
                new ol.style.Style({
                  image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                      color: color
                    })
                  })
                })
              ];
            }
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If maps are sharing a source and view a layer will need to be defined for each map, so you can create a shared style function which receives the map (or some other id) to indicate which map is being styled

```
  var map1 = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: sharedSource,
        style: function(feature){
          return sharedStyleFunction(feature, map1)
        }
      })
    ],
    target: 'map1',
    view: sharedView
  });

  var map2 = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: sharedSource,
        style: function(feature){
          return sharedStyleFunction(feature, map2)
        }
      })
    ],
    target: 'map2',
    view: sharedView
  });
```

Comment: I´m sorry that was a big mistake of my. I want to change the style based on the map. Your given answer is working very well for different views!!!!

Comment: I try to explain what i want. I´ve got a view, but two maps. These maps are shown the same views and the same sources, but i want to have to different styles for the vector source.